# Installshield / MSI Editing Responsive Transform

Tags: windows-installer, transform, installshield, packaging

Is it possible to directly edit a responsive transform (MST) without having to go through all the steps that originally performed to create the original mst?

I am editing a transform that a previous developer created and would like to retain his selections as oppose to possibly responding with a different selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Right click the MST file and select Edit with InstallShield.
- The Open Transform Wizard will appear.  Click Next.
- It'll ask you for the base MSI that the MST relates to.  Browse for
  it and click Next.
- Add any additional transforms you might have ( you can apply more
  then one so maybe you shouldn't edit his at all )
- Click Next
- Click Finish

Now you can use InstallShield to modify the transform and save it when you are done.

Comment: and the previous responses will be maintained?

Comment: Yes. But make a copy of the .MST before you do this just in case.